# Dont understand why i have problem like this: '{': no matching token found

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    T** m_iArr;
    int size_row;
    int size_col;
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int size_row_BuUser, int size_col_BuUser);
    int count();
};
template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix()
{
    size_col = 0;
    size_row = 0;
    m_iArr = new T * [size_row];
    for (int i = 0; i < size_row; i++)
    {
        m_iArr[i] = new T[size_col];
        for (int j = 0; j < size_col; j++)
        {
            m_iArr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int size_row_BuUser, int size_col_BuUser)
{
    size_row = size_col_BuUser;
    size_col = size_row_BuUser;
    m_iArr = new T * [size_row];
    for (int i = 0; i < size_row; i++)
    {
        m_iArr[i] = new T[size_col];
        for (int j = 0; j < size_col; j++)
        {
            m_iArr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "Matrix for random enter - 1\nMatrix for user enter -2" << endl << "Please enter:";
    int l = 1;
    cin >> l;
    switch (l)
    {
    case 1:
        for (int i = 0; i < size_row; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < size_col; j++)
            {
                m_iArr[i][j] = rand() % 99;
            }
        break;
    case 2:
        for (int i = 0; i < size_row; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < size_col; j++)
            {
                cout << "a[" << i << "]" << "[" << j << "]" << "=";
                cin >> m_iArr[i][j];
            }
        break;
    }
}
template<class T>
int Matrix<T>::count()
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_row; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size_col; j++)
        {
            if (m_iArr[i][j] < (m_iArr[i][j - 1])  **line 74**
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (j == n - 1)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    cout << count << endl;
        return count;
}
```

When I run my code I get a mistake. I don't understand why I have a mistake in the 74 line, help, please.
This is a mistake **'{': no matching token found**. Who knows what to do? I think that maybe I miss any bracket, but I revise a few times, and everything in its place.
Maybe the mistake is not only in the 74 line, but I don't know.

Comment: Typo? `if (m_iArr[i][j] < (m_iArr[i][j - 1])` -> `if (m_iArr[i][j] < (m_iArr[i][j - 1]))` (unmatched parentheses `(`)?

Comment: These typos are really hard to spot, especially when you make them yourself. What I do when really mysterious things happen: use an editor that can show matching parentheses, and check every single one moving outwards from the place of mystery.

Comment: Or start from scratch from empty, and add a class at a time, compile.  Add some more code, compile.  Repeat this until the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis

`if (m_iArr[i][j] < (m_iArr[i][j - 1])`

Should be:

`if (m_iArr[i][j] < (m_iArr[i][j - 1])  )`

Comment: No, there's one opening parenthesis too many ;-)

Comment: A matter of choice I think.  Not needing parenthesizes is different from using them to visually clarify code.

Comment: lol, I didn't get the joke at first.@molbdnilo